# SOAP Header: Communication secured between Flex and C#

Tags: c#, apache-flex, security, web-services, soapheader

I am working with Flex, Webservices and C# and I would like to secure the access on my web services through SOAP.

I spent 2 days on this problem:

My asmx file where i describe my webmethod:

```
    public ServiceAuthHeader CustomSoapHeader  = new ServiceAuthHeader();

    [SoapHeader("CustomSoapHeader")]
    [WebMethod(Description = "Return Somme")]
    public int getTotal(int x, int y)
    {
        ServiceAuthHeaderValidation.Validate(CustomSoapHeader);
        var total = x+y;
        return total;
    }


  public class ServiceAuthHeader : SoapHeader
    {
        // SoapHeader for authentication
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
    }
```

Then I wrote a class to check if the
 content of SOAP Header is
 good.

```
public class ServiceAuthHeaderValidation
{

[SoapHeader("soapHeader")]
[WebMethod(Description = "Check Header")]
public ServiceAuthHeader Validate(ServiceAuthHeader soapHeader)
{
    if (soapHeader == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("No soap header was specified.");                    
    }
    if (soapHeader.Username ==null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(soapHeader.Username);
        throw new NullReferenceException("Username was not supplied for authentication in SoapHeader!");
    }
    if (soapHeader.Password == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("Password was not supplied for authentication in SoapHeader.");
    }

    if (soapHeader.Username != "JOE") || soapHeader.Password != "JOE")
    {
        throw new Exception("Please pass the proper username and password for this service.");


   }
    return true;
}
```

}

So far I think I'm right.

But while i want to implement it in Flex:

```
var q1:QName=new QName("http://localhost:59399/Service1.asmx?wsdl", "Header1");
        header1=new SOAPHeader(q1, {String:"JOE",String JOE});
        _serviceControl.addHeader(header1);
```

I get a NullReferenceException on my username, which seems to be not supply.

My Webservice works, except when I try to implement:

```
ServiceAuthHeaderValidation.Validate(CustomSoapHeader);
```

Could someone reply me in order to know what is missing ? or my mistake..

THank you for your time.

So far StackoverFlow helped me a lot by reading different answers but today I stay stuck on it. If someone can help.

Comment: Your Flex code doesn't give me much to go on. Are you using the WebService tag inside the QName component?  Have you read this document about adding headers to Soap Requests from Flex?  
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=dataservices_099_32.html

Answer (score 0):

I just use a custom XML:

```
    public function addUserCredentials(username:String, passwordHash:String):ISoapInvocation
    {
        var headerDetails:XML =
            <Security xmlns={wsse}>
                <UsernameToken>
                    <Username>{username}</Username>
                    <Password>{passwordHash}</Password>
                </UsernameToken>
            </Security>;

        securityHeader = new SOAPHeader(securityQName, headerDetails);

        return this;
    }
```

Keep in mind that using {} inside an E4X definition *looks like* a binding that updates, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, Sophistifunk

I finally added in my generated AS sub class.

```
var header1:SOAPHeader;
        var q1:QName = new QName("http://localhost:80/", "Header");     
        header1 = new SOAPHeader(q1, {});
        var a:XML = <AuthHeader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://localhost:80/">
                    <UserLogin>Joe</UserLogin> 
                    <mdp>test</mdp> 
                    </AuthHeader>
        header1.content =  a;
        _serviceControl.addHeader(header1);
```

But when we implement a new WebService in Flex 4 through its IDE, everything is generated in AS.

But The way to manage the header sucks really.

That should take in charge automatically the security Header.. I mean create a function setLogin or setpassword bindable from or mxml application.

Anyway.

If someone know a way to take in charge the Header of SOAP through a better way.